# “Apurar” como sinónimo de “averiguar” y de “apresurar”

Tags: significado

En el Quijote, primera parte, cap. XXI, dice don Quijote a Sancho sobre un manteo que recibió y por el cual todavía guarda enojo:

> ¿Qué pie sacaste cojo, qué costilla quebrada, qué cabeza rota, para
>   que no se te olvide aquella burla? Que, **bien apurada la cosa**, burla
>   fue y pasatiempo; que a no entenderlo yo ansí, ya yo hubiera vuelto
>   allá, y hubiera hecho en tu venganza más daño que el que hicieron los
>   griegos por la robada Elena.

Por contexto, por nota al pie y por comparación con el portugués (donde *apurar* significa "investigar" o "resumir" o "contabilizar") comprendí inmediatamente el sentido de la expresión *bien apurada*, pero di por hecho que era uno de tantos arcaísmos. Sin embargo veo que en el DLE el <strike>primer</strike> tercer significado de *apurar* es

> **tr.** Averiguar o desentrañar la verdad ahincadamente o exponerla sin
>   omisión.

Por mi parte y fuera de la literatura siempre he usado *apurar* en el sentido que creo es más común en América, es decir, como "apresurar". Una cosa apurada no es una cosa investigada o bien observada sino una cosa hecha con prisa o apresuramiento (*«de apuro»* o *«a los apurones»* diríamos acá).

Mi pregunta es: ¿se utiliza ***apurar*** realmente con frecuencia como "investigar" (o en usos similares)? ¿En qué dialectos y en qué registros del habla? Se agradecen ejemplos.

Comment: @walen Pero entonces ¿se dice en España más bien "estoy apurado" o "estoy con / tengo prisa"?

Comment: @walen Entiendo, son connotaciones diferentes. Acá en una situación de mucho que hacer en poco tiempo más que "apurado" decimos "complicado" ("me agarrás complicado" o "estoy complicado ahora").

Comment: Aunque conozco  *apurar* con el sentido de prisa que le dan en América nunca lo he oído usar a españoles. Lo normal es usar el verbo *apurar* con el significado de acabar algo (p.e.: apura el vaso) o en su forma pronominal como sinónimo de preocuparse. Con el significado que apuntas en la pregunta tampoco lo he oído nunca.

Comment: @walen Esa tercera acepción era la segunda del Diccionario de Autoridades. Otras, como la de "apremiar, dar prisa" son mucho más recientes.

Comment: ¿Estaba viendo otra edición del DLE quizá? Acabo de corregir la pregunta, es el tercer significado, no el primero. Se mantiene la pregunta, porque ni el primero ni el segundo corresponden al que yo utilizo.

Comment: El Quijote tiene un lenguaje arcaico. Creo que hay que buscar le significado inicial de apurar, que es el de hacer puro, purificar, ¿probablemente exponer la pura verdad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De las posibles acepciones de *[apurar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3LepWPi)* que se leen en el diccionario (y que no están marcadas como "poco usadas" o "en desuso"):

> 1. tr. Acabar o agotar.
> 2. tr. Extremar, llevar hasta el cabo.
> 3. tr. Averiguar o desentrañar la verdad ahincadamente o exponerla sin omisión.
> 4. tr. Afligir, acongojar o preocupar. U. t. c. prnl.
> 5. tr. Apremiar, dar prisa. En Am., u. m. c. prnl.
> 6. tr. Molestar a alguien de modo que se enfade o pierda la paciencia.

yo diría que las más usadas son la 1, la 2, la 4 y la 5. Ejemplos:

- Se puede apurar un vaso de vino (acabarlo o agotarlo).
- Se puede apurar el tiempo de un examen (alargar el examen hasta llevarlo al final del plazo permitido).
- Puedes ir apurado para no llegar tarde a clase (apremiar, darse prisa).
- Puedes estar apurado por haber llegado tarde a clase (afligido, preocupado).

Sin embargo, esa acepción 3 la verdad es que me extraña que no haya sido marcada como "poco usada", dado que es casi igual de vieja que su acepción original, que sí lo está:

> 7. tr. p. us. Purificar algo separando lo impuro o extraño.

Si nos vamos a NTLLE, ya Covarrubias definía la palabra en 1611 con la misma primera acepción que luego usa el *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1726):

> Purificar y limpiar de excrementeos y de la matéria crassa alguna cosa: como la plata, oro, y otros metáles, acrisolándolos, y purgándolos de las heces que tienen, para que queden acendrádos.

Así queda claro por qué se dice *a + purar = hacer puro*. Su primera acepción metafórica es evidente, y equivale a la actual acepción 3:

> Metaphoricamente es averiguar y llegar à saber de raíz y con fundamento alguna cosa: como apurar una noticia, un cuento, una mentira, &c.

Valga como ejemplo este refrán que también recoge el diccionario:

> Quien las cosas mucho apúra, no tiene vida segúra. Refr. que enseña evitar la curiosidád desordenada en saber cosas ajénas, para no caer en perniciosos inconvenientes, que trahe este vicio al mismo que de él se vence.

La verdad es que no recuerdo haber visto en la actualidad este uso de *apurar* por ninguna parte. Puede que sea cuestión de tiempo que el DLE marque esa acepción 3 como "poco usada", o puede que solo se use en registros cultos. Ningún caso de todos los que me aparecen en el CREA refleja este significado.

Comment: En Argentina, he oído (y uso coloquialmente) "apurar" en la versión tercera de las definiciones que citas, para conminar a alguien por una respuesta rápida o definición sobre algo

Comment: Por ejemplo, 

> _"si te apuro, ¿cuál opción es la tuya la primera o segunda?"_

Comment: Entiendo que está muy cercana a la definición quinta —de apremiar— pero el uso comúnmente tiene una connotación asociada a _revelar_